# cloudfoundry-jquery-rails in place of jquery-rails

Tags: cloud-foundry

When deploying to cloud-foundry its [advised to change](http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/frameworks/ruby/rails-3-1.html) from `'jquery-rails'` gem to `'cloudfoundry-jquery-rails'`

```
 # For Ruby 1.9 Cloud Foundry requires a tweak to the jquery-rails gem.
 # gem 'jquery-rails'
   gem 'cloudfoundry-jquery-rails'
```

[so that jquery can seamlessly work with cloudfoundry](https://github.com/estahn/cloudfoundry-jquery-rails#readme).

What are those fixes refered to in [this](https://github.com/estahn/cloudfoundry-jquery-rails#readme) that are necessary to make it work on cloud-foundry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for this is a little out of date and is in the process of being updated. For Rails 3.1 this may well be the case, but certainly not for 3.2, it should work fine as is.

Comment: But what are the changes even if for that version?

Comment: I think it was all to do with the way some assets are compiled at run-time which due to the lack of JS engine, cloudfoundry.com can't do. As I say, as long as you pre-compile your assets I have found this version is not needed.